# Chemistry of water under pressure

Tags: pressure, water, physical-chemistry

What is the structure of water under extreme pressure, like the bottom of the ocean on a moon like Europa.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by the term 'structure'.  Are we talking chemical structure, possible crystalline structures, what?

Comment: The bottom of the ocean is not extreme enough to do much to the structure of water. Now, the center of Jupiter, that is another question... Googling 'high pressure ice phase diagram' will get you the info you want to know.